# Why does removing yaml front matter stop Jekyll from converting md file to html

Tags: jekyll

I've inherited a process that converts markdown content into html using jekyll.

If I remove the yaml front matter between ---, by client request to simplify the process for editors,

```
---
product: Product Name
capability: testing
infotype: Overview
audience:

---

# Testing file 2

This is another testing file.
```

The jekyll build doesn't convert the file.

```
# Testing file 2

This is another testing file.
```

When I have the front matter in the testing 2 file I see the following in the log when running `build --verbose`

```
Rendering: user-administration/testing-file-2.md
Pre-Render Hooks: user-administration/testing-file-2.md
Rendering Markup: user-administration/testing-file-2.md
Rendering Layout: user-administration/testing-file-2.md
```

but without the front matter there is no message in the log related to testing-file-2.md

This testing-file-2.md is part of a collection of other files that have metadata. They are render into an html website but not the testing-file-2.md when the metadata is removed.

Is there a way for jekyll to build and render files without front matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jekyll does not ignore any files. Rather, for each file, it decides whether the file is:

- a static file, which can be copied as-is to the output folder (`_site`), or
- a file to be processed first.

Markdown files (`.md`) are processed by [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) and [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) *if* they start with YAML frontmatter:

```
---
---
```

otherwise they are treated as static files, and copied to `_site` with no processing.

There is a workaround that might work for you using `include_relative`; but it may cause more trouble for your client's editors than it's worth, depending how they work.

You can include a static file inside a file to be processed. Your static file might be `plain-text.md`:

```
# Static text file

This is a file with no YAML frontmatter.
```

Then, separately, you create a markdown file with frontmatter that will include the plain-text file inside it. Say, `processed-text.md`:

```
---
---
{% include_relative plaintext.md %}
```

Then your plain text will be processed and appear on your site as `/processed-text`. Think of the file `processed-text.md` as a kind of template for holding `plain-text.md`.

You'll want to see [the docs on `include_relative`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file), especially the fact that the file to be included can't be above the including file in the file system.

Comment: If you want your file to be processed/converted to html, put ---
--- right at the beginning, no new line. Thanks Arthur

Answer (score 1):

I've [read](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) that it's a requirement to have at minimum at empty front matter or jekyll will ignore the file

```
---
---
```